# how to use sql along with vb.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

I am doing this for the first time, how do I use SQL via vb.net to insert, update and delete data in the database. Do I need to set up anything before I can use SQL? If I shift my executable app to a different computer do I need to install SQL in that computer as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [a number of tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?q=vb+.net+database+tutorial) which can get you started.

As for running the applications on a different computer, it depends on where the database is located.  Generally the database and the application are two separate things, the latter is simply accessing the former.  Can the other target computer also access the database?  Will the database be installed on a server accessible to the target machine?  As long as it can see the database and its config file is correct, it should work fine.

Comment: If I distribute my app and my client doesn't have sql installed , will the program still work ? I don't know on the client side how he / she will access the databse

Comment: It sounds like you want to package a new local database with each install.  Look into SqlLite for that.  The idea there is that a database "file" will be included alongside each install of the application.  So the client wouldn't need a database of their own.

Comment: Tha'ts a fantastic idea. Is SQlLite free or do I have to get a license for each package distribution ?

Comment: I'm not sure about distributing it to clients, but I think it's free.  You'll want to research the licensing yourself to make sure.

Comment: Can you provide some link or something which would help me with SQlLite and vb.net ?

Comment: Google is your best bet.  (I'm writing this on a phone right now, bear with me.) I believe SQLLite is made by Microsoft, so should be functionally very similar to MS SQL, just stripped down (and not very high-end).

Comment: I tried hard (almost 1 hour) but unable to find the executable version for sQLite for .net 4 . The home-site has been shifted to some other place where I am having trouble finding the new version. Please, can you give me the link ?

Comment: Okay, with p.campbell's help  I got it to work, thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty broad. It's like asking "How do I drive a vehicle?"  There are many different types of vehicles: boats, cars, rockets, airplanes, skateboards, etc.  To tell you how to drive a vehicle we need to know what type of vehicle you want (or at least whether or not it's a land vehicle, water vehicle, etc).  Likewise, there are many different ways to  "use SQL via vb.net".  Do you want to do Web development, standard Windows apps, console apps, WPF?

The best starting point is probably to learn pure ADO.NET since all of the other methods are built on top of it.  Learn the basics before getting into LINQ, Entity Framework, etc.

I'd start here: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson01.aspx